# If $\Sigma=\lbrace(\neg\alpha),(\neg\beta),(\alpha\vee\beta)\rbrace$, show that $\Sigma$ is inconsistent.

Tags: propositional-calculus

> If $\Sigma=\lbrace(\neg\alpha),(\neg\beta),(\alpha\vee\beta)\rbrace$, show that there is some formula $\theta$ such that $\theta$ and $(\neg\theta)$ can be deduced from $\Sigma$ (i.e., that $\Sigma$ is inconsistent)

I understand I must come up with a formula that can be deduced from this set of hypotheses, but I am unsure how to begin thinking of a formula that would work in this scenario.

EDIT: I was able to solve, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you read the sentences you are given aloud and thought about what you might deduce?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @RossMillikan I am not given any sentences. I simply know what $\Sigma$ is and must come up with formula $\theta$ through my intuition

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a set of sentences.  $\alpha$ represents a sentence and $\lnot \alpha$ is its negation. Try to prove some things from them.

Comment: @JOSEPHGAFFNEY You are being asked to *demonstrate* that $\Sigma$ is *inconsistent*.   Now, if indeed these *three* formula form an inconsistent set, then any two among them will entail the negation of the third.  So select any two and show that they do.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\alpha\lor\beta$ is equivalent to $(\lnot \alpha)\to \beta$, by $\lnot\alpha$ and modus ponens, we have $\beta$. But $\lnot\beta$ by hypothesis, a contradiction.

See, also, [disjunctive syllogism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism):

$$\frac{\Sigma\vdash \lnot\alpha, \Sigma\vdash (\alpha\lor \beta)}{\Sigma\vdash \beta}.$$

Answer (score 3):

> I am unsure how to begin thinking of a formula that would work in this scenario.

Hint: Given $\neg \alpha$ and $\neg \beta$, what can you infer about the truth of of $\alpha \lor \beta$? What can then be said about $\neg (\alpha \lor \beta)$ under $\Sigma$? Can we (if so, how?) deduce $\alpha \lor \beta$ from $\Sigma$?
Combine these two observations to show that both $\alpha \lor \beta$ and $\neg (\alpha \lor \beta)$ can be deduced from $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to get the solution from this!